# Issue with laravel file uploads on local storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I am using

```
$request->file('photo')->store('public/photos');
```

to store files in `public/photos` directory under `storage`.

Created a link to `storage` from `public` directory using `artisan storage:link`. The output of

```
$request->file('photo')->store('public/photos');
```

is stored in `db` against the `photo` field. While retrieving the photo in view, I use `asset()` helper which output the link as

```
domain.com/storage/public/photos/photo.jpg
```

which returns 404 error. It should actually return

```
domain.com/storage/photos/photo.jpg
```

as `public/storage` is linked to `app/storage/public`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You save it like this... `$request->file('photo')->store('public/photos');`

Store is the location to save the photo.

Remove `public` from here `->store('public/photos');`

Comment: In that case, it will simply store in `/storage`, but the symlink is with `/storage/public` from `public` directory of laravel

Comment: why dont you use `storage_path()` then?